# center div inside the browser viewing window

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want to center it vertically within the browser view.

In other words, if the user scrolled down, I want the div to be shown at the same center position within the current Y axie that the user is viewing.

Thanks

Comment: a wrapper with position: relative , and the specific DIV with absolute top 50%

Comment: A general good practice (on stackoverflow or anywhere else) is to post the relevant chunk of code from what you've got that's not working, so that others can see exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, try this:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -50px; /* half the div's height */
}
```